# Implicit curves in higher dimensions with differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

We know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, an implicit curve can be described by $$F(x,y)=0\,,$$ where $F$ satisfies certain regularity conditions, and normal / tangential vectors can be derived explicitly. I have been looking for a generalisation of the implicit description to higher dimensions, and in particular in terms of **differential forms**.

The idea comes intuitively from the fact that for $(x^1, \ldots, x^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, an implicit hypersurface $\mathcal{M}$ can be described by $F(x^i) = 0$ with additional regularity condition, where $\dim \mathcal{M} = n-1$.

One is tempted to generalise the claim to a set of "regular" functions $F_1(x^i), \ldots, F_m(x^i)$, $m < n$, such that
$$F_a(x^i) = 0\,, \qquad a = 1, \dots, m\,,$$
describes an $(n-m)$-dimensional submanifold. Two cases with $m=1$ have been described above. A **curve**, which is a $1$-dimensional submanifold, can therefore be described by $m=n-1$ such equations.

My guess is that this could be summarised by the description $\mathrm{d} f \wedge \mathrm{d} g = 0$, where $f$ and $g$ are scalar functions on a real differential manifold $\Sigma$, $\dim \Sigma = n$. The degeneracy condition contains exactly $(n-1)$ equations in terms of the components.

Does this implicit description of curves exists in the literature? In particular, I would like to know about the tangential / normal vectors of the implicit curve.

Comment: What is your proposed relation between $f,g$ and the $F_a$? You'll normally see this formulated with the functions $F$ gathered into a map $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m,$ with the non-degeneracy condtion required for the level set $F = 0$ to be a submanifold being that the derivative matrix $DF$ is surjective. I don't think differential forms get involved very naturally.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you for the comment. I'll try to reformulate my question a bit soon because I didn't want to study the relation between $f$, $g$ and $F_a$.

I was given a non-negative function $f$. The function $g = \langle \mathrm{d} f, \mathrm{d} f \rangle$, so that I want to study the curve along which $\mathrm{d} f$ and $\mathrm{d} g$ are aligned. This leads to $\mathrm{d} f \wedge \mathrm{d} g = 0 $. 

Furthermore, I want to impose the condition that $\mathrm{d}f$ is also tangential to the curve. Therefore, I want to know about the tangential and normal vectors of the curve.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I disagree. The rank condition can naturally be formulated as $dF_1\wedge\dots\wedge dF_m\ne 0$, and the foliation specified by $dF_1 = \dots = dF_m = 0$.